# Go + Fyne Framework: Facing Package Issue, Seeking Assistance

Tags: go, fyne

[Facing Errors for Specific Modules in Go with Fyne Framework](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agiPr.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToVga.png)
I'm encountering an issue with Fyne in Go. Despite having the latest versions of both Fyne and Go, I'm consistently facing a problem where modules, specifically 'fyne.io/fyne/v2/container/unit,' cannot be found. I've tried reinstalling multiple times without success. Seeking help to resolve this persistent module-related error.

### Code:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    myApp := app.New()
    myWindow := myApp.NewWindow("Hello Fyne")

    myButton := widget.NewButton("Click me!", func() {
        fmt.Println("Button Clicked!")
    })

    myContainer := container.New(
        layout.NewVBoxLayout(),
        layout.NewSpacer(), // Spacer to push the button to the center
        myButton,
        layout.NewSpacer(), // Spacer for better layout
    )

    myWindow.SetContent(myContainer)

    myWindow.ShowAndRun()
}
```

---

Updated Fyne and Go Versions, Installed Packages - Still Facing Specific Module Errors

Comment: Please post your code and error as text rather than an image

Comment: run `go mod tidy` see if it helps

Comment: The namespace are wrong U should use fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout and Not container/layout

Answer (score 0):

There is no such package as `fyne.io/fyne/v2/container/unit` and there never has been. This is not a packaging issue.